# Recursive binary tree

Tags: c#, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

Basically my problem is that I need an addNode method which signature is something like this:

```
addNode(Node thisNode, Node toAdd)
```

My current methods signature is:

```
AddRecursively(null, usersInput);
```

null (node) because as it is a recursive method I need to pass the values back into the method. usersInput is an int.

I'm clueless how to do what I have been told to do while still using recursion.

Please note note : 
Please try to explain your code in a simple fashion if possible, I'm not too great at programming.

My code should work because it's based on my old code which did work but I haven't tested it yet and Node findNode has been left in because I'm supposed to use two nodes but I'm clueless how to do that to be quite honest.

```
public void AddRecursively(Node findNode, Node findNextNode, int usersInput)//don't need findNode i think
{
    if (root.value == null)
    {
        root.value = usersInput; //if no root, make it (everytime it is run it will have no root)
    }
    else if (usersInput > root.value && root.right == null)
    {
        root.right.value = usersInput; //first right of node
    }
    else if (usersInput < root.value && root.left == null)
    {
        root.left.value = usersInput; //first left of node 
    }
    //recursive
    else if (usersInput > root.right.value && root.right != null && findNextNode == null)
    {
        findNextNode = root.right; //setting up recursive right
    }
    else if (usersInput < root.left.value && root.left != null && findNextNode == null)
    {
        findNextNode = root.left; //setting up recursive left
    }
    //adding values before doing recursive
    else if (usersInput > findNextNode.right.value && findNextNode.right == null)
    {
        findNextNode.right.value = usersInput; //if the next right is empty add
    }
    else if (usersInput < findNextNode.left.value && findNextNode.left == null)
    {
        findNextNode.left.value = usersInput; //if next left is empty add
    }
    //recursive, should be able to handle left.left.right for example as findNextNode could be right.right then it could = right.right.left
    else if (usersInput > findNextNode.right.value && findNextNode.right != null)
    {
        findNextNode = findNextNode.right;
        AddRecursively(null, findNextNode, usersInput);
    }
    else if (usersInput < findNextNode.left.value && findNextNode.left != null)
    {
        findNextNode = findNextNode.left;
        AddRecursively(null, findNextNode, usersInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get the question, your code doesn't work?

Comment: @AlejandroPiad My code does work but it doesn't take in two input nodes which are which node the add method is at and the next node it wants to visit. Currently it only takes in what node it wants to go to.. I'm sorry this is such a badly worded post! I'm just not too sure what to even say myself.. The only issue with my code is it's not done the way the lead developer wants.. (I'm learning c#)

Comment: Recursion is a way to code something difficult in a concise way. This piece of art looks like a consise thing written in a difficult was :-)

Comment: @user3245390 I think the issue might be that your method is an instance method, hence the node your are currently at is `this`, so there is no need to specify it as a parameter. From the signature the "lead developer" wants, I guess he expects this to be a static method, instead of an instance one, hence you would need to pass the current node as well as the one to add. It has nothing to do with recursion, both ways are done recursively (instance or static). Is just whether the `this` is implied or explicitly declared. Perhaps you need to think if you want an instance or a static method...

Comment: @lboshuizen Thank you for the compliment :)! Just a little update in regards to the discussion I'm having with the lead dev. He doesn't have time to go over what "isn't correct" but he said this. Maybe it helps clear up what I'm after (quote what he said) : "I doubt I'll have time to come round and do that today I'm afraid.  You need the two nodes because you need to have the one that you are adding and you need the one you're currently looking at.  They shouldn't be available to you any other way unless your code isn't correct"

Comment: @AlejandroPiad It can't be that because he told me never to use static (I think he'd explicitly state for me to use it when need be), please read the comment I made (above this one) as I comment some more info that might help you understand. By the way thanks for the comments! I really do appreciate any and all the help I can get.

Comment: Won't this crash `if (... && findNextNode.left == null) ... findNextNode.left.value = usersInput;`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I just tested it now. It does, I looked at my previous code and I did  Node nextNode = new Node(usersInput); (the method was very different back then). Easy enough to fix though ^_^. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the way I would prefer to do it, but in order to answer your specific question, I'll stick to the signature you propose.

First I'll asume you have the following class structure:

```
class BinaryTree<T> where T: IComparable<T> {
    private Node root;

    // ....

    // The public Add interface (might be different for you)
    public void Add(T value) {
        if (this.root == null) {
            // Handle the special empty case
            this.root = new Node() { Value = value };
        } 
        else {
            // Just call the private one with the right values
            this.Add(this.root, new Node() { Value = value });
        }
    }

    // This is where the recursive magic happens
    private void Add(Node current, Node toAdd) {
        // This one comes next...
    }

    class Node {
        public T Value;
        public Node Left;
        public Node Right;
    }
}
```

I'm using a different class for the tree itself that `Node` because it makes it easier to deal with `null` nodes, and if later on you decide to make a balanced tree (AVL, Red Black, etc.) it will be a lot easier to manipulate `Node` instances from outside.

Besides, the generic type `T` might not be nullable, but `Node` is. Note that `T` needs to be `IComparable<T>`. In your case, `int` suffices.

Now, lets move onto the recursive method.

```
// ....

private void Add(Node current, Node toAdd) {
    // From here on neither `current.Value` nor `toAdd.Value` are ever null
    if (toAdd.Value.CompareTo(current.Value) <= 0) {
         // We go left
         if (current.Left == null) {
             current.Left = toAdd;
         }
         else {
             Add(node.Left, toAdd);
         }
    }
    else {
         // We go right
         if (current.Right == null) {
             current.Right = toAdd;
         }
         else {
             Add(node.Right, toAdd);
         }          
    }
}
```

I think this is it.

Now, if you ask me, the method could be made a a bit shorter if we allow the private `Add` implementation to return the added node.

```
// ....

private Node Add(Node current, Node toAdd) {
    if (current == null) {
         return toAdd;
    }

    if (toAdd.Value.CompareTo(current.Value) <= 0) {
         current.Left = Add(current.Left, toAdd);
    }
    else {
         current.Right = Add(current.Right, toAdd);
    }

    return current;
}
```

And then the public `Add` is also simpler

```
public void Add(T value) {
    this.root = Add(this.root, new Node() { Value = value });
}
```

As @Iboshuizen said, recursion allow you say complex things with simple statements.

Hope it makes your boss happy ;).

Comment: In a complete implementation of a binary search tree you would have a `Find` recursive method that returns either the found node or the closest node in the tree. Then both `Add` and `Remove` can be easily implemented by calling `Find`.